# Finding cumprod for dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I've a (triangular)data frame
i,e:DF1:

```
2016A   NaN NaN  2.5  6.5  NaN  NaN
2016B   NaN 5.32 6.3  NaN  NaN  NaN
2017A   NaN 9.4  5.6  NaN  NaN  NaN
2018B   4.5 NaN  5.6  NaN  NaN  NaN
2018C   NaN 6.5  4.3  NaN  NaN  NaN
2019A   5.3 NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

I've to find the **cumprod** for this dataframe.

I tried this code:

```
df2= df1.iloc[:, ::-1].cumprod(axis=1).iloc[:, ::-1]
```

But result is same as df1

The result should look like:

```
2016A   NaN NaN   16.25  6.5  NaN   NaN
2016B   NaN 33.51  6.3   NaN  NaN   NaN
2017A   NaN 52.64  5.6   NaN  NaN   NaN
2018B   25.2 NaN   5.6   NaN  NaN   NaN
2018C   NaN 27.95  4.3   NaN  NaN   NaN
2019A   5.3  NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN   NaN
```

Thank you for your time :)

Comment: Your code working well, for you not?

Comment: There is some error?

Comment: I don't have column name or row name to data frame :

Comment: error is like :TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

Comment: What is `print (df.head(2).to_dict())` ?

Comment: {'2016A': {0: '2016B', 1: '2017A'}, 'NaN': {0: nan, 1: nan}, 'NaN.1': {0: 5.32, 1: 9.4}, 2.5: {0: 6.3, 1: 5.6}, 6.5: {0: nan, 1: nan}, 'NaN.2': {0: nan, 1: nan}, 'NaN.3': {0: nan, 1: nan}}

Comment: Data are from file? because columns are data from first row, for avoid it need `header=None` in `read_csv`

Comment: Yes, data are from xlsx file, so dataframe may have like that also. So in that case how to find cumprod.

Comment: print (df1.select_dtypes(exclude=np.number).columns) :  for this ; Index(['2016A', 2.5], dtype='object')

Comment: Is possible use `header=None` in `read_excel` ?

Comment: Answer was edited.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be working well, but there is one thing required. It is to not do the calculations on the first column:

```
>>> df.set_index(df.iloc[:, 0].name).iloc[:, ::-1].cumprod(axis=1).iloc[:, ::-1].reset_index()
       0     1       2      3    4   5   6
0  2016A   NaN     NaN  16.25  6.5 NaN NaN
1  2016B   NaN  33.516   6.30  NaN NaN NaN
2  2017A   NaN  52.640   5.60  NaN NaN NaN
3  2018B  25.2     NaN   5.60  NaN NaN NaN
4  2018C   NaN  27.950   4.30  NaN NaN NaN
5  2019A   5.3     NaN    NaN  NaN NaN NaN
>>>
```

Comment: I think it is index.

Comment: it is not working, shows this error:TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

Comment: @MichaelScofield What does `df.dtypes` output?

Answer (score 0):

EDIT1:

First use `header=None` for avoid convert first row of data to columns names:

```
df1 = pd.read_excel(file, header=None)
```

There is one or more non numeric columns, you can find them by:

```
print (df1.select_dtypes(exclude=np.number).columns)
```

If all columns should be numeric exclude `0, col1, col2` use:

```
df1 = df1.set_index([0, 'col1','col2']).apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
```

And then use your solution:

```
df2 = df1.iloc[:, ::-1].cumprod(axis=1).iloc[:, ::-1]
```

---

If first column is not index:

```
lens = len(df1.columns)
df1.update(df1.iloc[:, lens:0:-1].cumprod(axis=1).iloc[:, lens:0:-1])
print (df1)
       0     1       2      3    4   5   6
0  2016A   NaN     NaN  16.25  6.5 NaN NaN
1  2016B   NaN  33.516   6.30  NaN NaN NaN
2  2017A   NaN  52.640   5.60  NaN NaN NaN
3  2018B  25.2     NaN   5.60  NaN NaN NaN
4  2018C   NaN  27.950   4.30  NaN NaN NaN
5  2019A   5.3     NaN    NaN  NaN NaN NaN
```

Or create `index` first by first column:

```
df1 = df1.set_index(df1.columns[0])
df2 = df1.iloc[:, ::-1].cumprod(axis=1).iloc[:, ::-1]
```